# Explicitly set object in CDI Session scope?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, scope, cdi

I have a Java web filter that does some initial processing of incoming requests.  Within this filter, I'd like to be able to set a value in the CDI `Session` scope when certain conditions are met.  I have not found any documentation that says that this is possible, however.  With JBoss Seam, I was able to call `Contexts.getSessionContext()` and then set my scope values programmatically.  Is there any equivalent within JavaEE 7 and CDI that will let me take a Java object and add it to the `Session` scope?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject Bean into CDI Context programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538679/inject-bean-into-cdi-context-programmatically)

Comment: You know, you're absolutely right.  And the sad part is, that was my question!  Sorry for the duplicate!  I don't remember asking it in the first place.