# How do I outject an object for CDI / Weld

Tags: java, jsf, session, cdi

I think it is a pretty basic question, but I haven´t found a solution yet.
How would I "outject" an object, which I would later like to have as an object to be injected.

Let´s say, we have ServiceA, which creates an Object

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceA {

  public void createObject() {

      MyObject myObject = callSomeService();
      ---> now put myObject into the session
  }
}
```

And another Service B should be able to use this object:

```
@Stateless
public class ServiceB {

  //should be available here
  @Inject
  private MyObject myObject

}
```

How would I do that?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Specifically, the producer method you need will look like this:

```
@Produces
@SessionScoped
public MyObject createSessionObject() {
    return callSomeService();
}
```

This will be called once for the session, the first time accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to use a Producer method.

> A producer method can allow you to select a bean implementation at
>   runtime, instead of at development time or deployment time. [~ Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkgkv.html)

You can find examples of how to use Producer methods online. [This tutorial](http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/java-ee-cdi-producer-methods-tutorial) seems useful.

Similar question:

- [Inject Bean into CDI Context programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21538679/inject-bean-into-cdi-context-programmatically)